# How to access the same variable by multiple processes C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, process

I have recently started learning how to program in C under Linux and have written the following code to create some processes:

```
void generate()
{    
  int pid;

  for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
  {
    pid = fork();  
  }

  if (pid<0)
  {
    printf("Error Fork");
    exit(1);
  }

  if(pid == 0)
  {
    printf("Fiu pid: %d --- Parinte pid: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    //count ++;
  }

  if(pid > 0 )
  {
    printf("Parinte pid: %d\n", getpid());
    //count++;
    wait();

  }
}
```

The question is: how should i declare/increment the count variable in order to print the total number of processes the function has created?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: Is that necessary? This is forking processes, not creating threads.

Comment: @FredLarson ah misread the question. I'm more of a thread kindof guy. :-P

Comment: It's actually a homework. The question sounds like this:

How many processes does the following code create:

for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
fork();

Determine the number without using a formula. Print the answer only once.

Comment: Here's a hint: each child process continues where its parent left off, and so does the parent. So the child processes will fork as well.

Comment: You don't access the *same* `count` variable. Each forked process has its own address space (so its *own* variable). To share memory, see [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) - and synchronization would need [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple.  `Fork` produces a child for each parent.  The answer is therefore 2^10 or 1024.

Put a `printf` after the `fork` and comment out the other extraneous output.  Run as

```
./a.out | sort | uniq | wc
```

The output is is 1024.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void generate()
{
  int pid;

  for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
  {
    pid = fork();
    printf("%d\n", getpid());
  }

  if (pid<0)
  {
    //printf("Error Fork");
    exit(1);
  }

  if(pid == 0)
  {
    //printf("Fiu pid: %d --- Parinte pid: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    //count ++;
  }

  if(pid > 0 )
  {
    //printf("Parinte pid: %d\n", getpid());
    //count++;
    wait(NULL);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    generate();

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Correct.  The first iteration of the loop turns 1 process into 2, and now i==2 in both of them.  The second iteration turns each of 2 processes into 2 (total 4), and now i==3 in all four of them.  And so on.

Comment: @Duck I see where I made a mistake in my logic. I'm going to withdraw my answer. Thank you for helping me figure it out.

Comment: The output in the terminal is fine. But is there any way to only print 1024? I'll ask my teacher for further explanation.

Comment: Change `wc` to `wc -l` and it will just print out the number of lines, which is the number of processes (including the original parent).

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are better approaches but.. You can append a new line/character to a temp file every time a child is created. Then you just have to count the lines/characters of the file.